# string.Substring not working correctly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I'm facing issue with string.Substring() in C#

my sample application is bellow.

```
string myString = " Jun30/13 DU SJ9802";
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(myString.Substring(0,15));
list.Add(myString.Substring(0, 10));
list.Add(myString.Substring(9, 3));
list.Add(myString.Substring(9, 4));
```

when I see the results, it shows as

myString.Substring(0,15)

" Jun30/13 DU SJ"

myString.Substring(0, 10)

" Jun30/13 "

**myString.Substring(9, 3)**

" DU"

**myString.Substring(9, 4)**

" DU "

It shows **wrong** sub string for **myString.Substring(9, 3)** and **myString.Substring(9, 4)**. correct sub string should be **"DU " and "DU S"**

any thoughts ?

Debug Image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRjC9.png

Comment: Remember, Substring is zero index based. The first character is 0, not 1.

Comment: 0-space 1-J 2-u 3-n 4-3 5-0 6-/ 7-1 8-3 9-space

Comment: not working as you expected != not working correctly

Comment: Please learn to [**read the documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx). If you had, you'd see that the first parameter, `startIndex`, is `The **zero-based** starting character position of a substring in this instance.` which would point out your problem.

Comment: Select isn't broken: http://pragmatictips.com/26.  Read that and  internalize it before you ask your next question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually working correctly. There is a leading space on the string and thus the ninth index is the space just before the `DU`. Consider this diagram:

```
 Jun30/13 DU SJ9802
0123456789
```

You're starting on the ninth index, and that's a space .

Comment: If the leading space is not intentional, then use `String.Trim()` to remove the leading and trailing white space. This would affect your index values for `String.Substring()` though.

Answer (score 3):

[`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) "starts at a specified character position and has a specified length".

In your case, if you look at your string:

```
" Jun30/13 DU SJ9802"
 0123456789
```

Position 9 is the space, so `9,3` should be `" DU"`, and `9,4` should be `" DU "`, exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot that character index starts with 0, not 1.

Comment: thanks a lot all, was my mistake, just took from debug console :(

Comment: @Harshana: Your mistake was not that you forgot that indices are zero based. Your mistake was that when you saw a difference between what you expected and what you got, you assumed that you were right and the implementation of an utterly simple method was wrong.